# How to get the last output of a file in terminal?

Tags: terminal, output

I am running a jar file in terminal and I want to do something with the last output that I see, which happens to be a System.out.print statement. I have tried:

- tail -1 myjar.jar
- $(!!)

but neither of them seem to work for me.

Comment: I'm rusty on java, but you want to tail the program's output, not the jarfile itself.  Something like `$ java myjar.jar | tail -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `java -jar myjar.jar | tail -1`

You want to pipe the output of your jar into `tail`. The pipe will connect the output stream of `java -jar myjar.jar` to the input stream of `tail -1`.

`tail -1 myjar.jar` will output the last line of the file `myjar.jar`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: `-jar`: that's the part I didn't know!

Comment: Im getting an Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile myjar.jar.. do I have to pipe it after I run it or on the same line?

Comment: You can't pipe it after you run it unless you store the output in some variable and piped the `echo`'d output. How have you been running the jar file in the terminal? Sounds like your jar is not executable.